# QUERY current month in google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

Quite simple question:
I want a query that filters the current month, I got this one working:

```
=query(Sheet1!A9:F; "select sum(D) where A >= date '2016-10-01' and A < date '2016-11-01'"; 0)
```

I need to get sth like

```
(...) where A >= "'Year(Today())'-'Month(Today())'-01" (...)
```

but that doesn't work.
:/

Answer (score 1):

Try using ["TODAY()"](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984?hl=en) in upper case instead of "Today()". I read in this [google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/wD7yGMnN21s) that this query statements are case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks - I used a workaround - I filled another cell with the current date and called this cell from within the query.

Answer (score 0):

This will query all the data from the 1st of the current month, to the last day of that same month.

```
A >= date '"&text(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and A <= date '"&text(EOMONTH(TODAY(),),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming as an example...

```
A        B        
10/2/23  data    
10/3/23  moredata  
11/6/23  evenmoredata
```

I use:

```
=query(A2:B4,"SELECT A, B WHERE MONTH(A) = '"&month(today())-1&"'")
```